# How to validate XMLs against a XSD using DOM with constraints?

Tags: xml, dom, xsd

Good evening colleagues.

I need to validate XMLs against a XSD using DOM.
Here are an abridged sample XML and the corresponding XSD.
You will note that the XML is valid, but I need to enforce two more constraints:

1. "LOT_MLT" <= "LOT_MIN" < "LOT_MAX"
2. "LOT_MAX" and "LOT_MIN" must be exact multiples of "LOT_MLT"

Is there a way to enforce these constraints with XSD and DOM? (I know how to do it without these two extra constraints.)

Thank you for your help.

XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <Import>
    <Prd>
        <PRD_COD>SBBl</PRD_COD> 
        <PRD_DESC>Small Box, black</PRD_DESC> 
        <LOT_MLT>128</LOT_MLT> 
        <LOT_MIN>128</LOT_MIN> 
        <LOT_MAX>256</LOT_MAX> 
        <INV_INI>0</INV_INI> 
    </Prd>
    <Prd>
        <PRD_COD>LBWh</PRD_COD> 
        <PRD_DESC>Large Box, white</PRD_DES> 
        <LOT_MLT>32</LOT_MLT> 
        <LOT_MIN>64</LOT_MIN> 
        <LOT_MAX>640</LOT_MAX> 
        <INV_INI>64</INV_INI> 
    </Prd>
  </Import
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Import">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>    

                <xs:element name="Prd" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="PRD_COD" type="xs:normalizedString"/>
                            <xs:element name="PRD_DES" type="xs:normalizedString"/>
                            <xs:element name="LOT_MLT" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>                
                            <xs:element name="LOT_MIN" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                            <xs:element name="LOT_MAX" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>          
                            <xs:element name="INV_INI" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:unique name="PRD_COD">
            <xs:selector xpath="Prd"/>
            <xs:field xpath="PRD_COD"/>
        </xs:unique>   

    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

The validation you need is possible to specify using `<xs:assert>` available in XSD 1.1. This is the full your schema modified accordingly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="Import">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>    

                <xs:element name="Prd" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="PRD_COD" type="xs:normalizedString"/>
                            <xs:element name="PRD_DESC" type="xs:normalizedString"/>
                            <xs:element name="LOT_MLT" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>                
                            <xs:element name="LOT_MIN" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                            <xs:element name="LOT_MAX" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>          
                            <xs:element name="INV_INI" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
                        </xs:sequence>

                        <xs:assert test="LOT_MLT &lt;= LOT_MIN and LOT_MIN &lt; LOT_MAX and
                                         LOT_MIN mod LOT_MLT = 0 and LOT_MAX mod LOT_MLT = 0"/>

                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:unique name="PRD_COD">
            <xs:selector xpath="Prd"/>
            <xs:field xpath="PRD_COD"/>
        </xs:unique>   

    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The restriction is specified with the `test` attribute in the `<xs:assert>`. The value of that attribute must be an XPath expression, which is evaluated against the context element (in this case `<Prd>`). The XPath expression is a single string. For clarity, I break it into two lines. The first line is to test your constraint (1), the second line is for the constraint (2).

The XML validator should be XSD 1.1 aware. To make sure it recognizes XSD 1.1, the `vc:minVersion` attribute is added in the `<xs:schema>` head. However, that is optional.

This is your XML that passed the validation with that schema (using XMLSpy):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Import xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/MySchemas/the_schema.xsd">
  <Prd>
      <PRD_COD>SBBl</PRD_COD>
      <PRD_DESC>Small Box, black</PRD_DESC>
      <LOT_MLT>128</LOT_MLT>
      <LOT_MIN>128</LOT_MIN>
      <LOT_MAX>256</LOT_MAX>
      <INV_INI>0</INV_INI>
  </Prd>
  <Prd>
      <PRD_COD>LBWh</PRD_COD>
      <PRD_DESC>Large Box, white</PRD_DESC>
      <LOT_MLT>32</LOT_MLT>
      <LOT_MIN>64</LOT_MIN>
      <LOT_MAX>640</LOT_MAX>
      <INV_INI>64</INV_INI>
  </Prd>
</Import>
```

The XSD file is linked to the XML with `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute in its root element. That's again optional and depends on a particular validator.

Now, you are talking about DOM, that you want to use it somehow for validation. DOM is not a tool, but a way to represent XML documents in memory, which is accessible via some API. That representation makes sense only in the context of some programming environment (e.g. Java to extract data from that XML or modify it). You just need some XSD 1.1 aware XML validator and, if you don't want to modify your XML with the schema reference, there must be a way to specify to it that schema, against which to validate.

P.S.

The following links may be interesting for those working with XML schemas and WSDL:

- High-performance universal **XML Schema Documentation Generator with diagrams**: http://www.flexdoc.xyz/flexdoc-xml/xsddoc/
- The same for WSDL & XSD together: http://www.flexdoc.xyz/flexdoc-xml/wsdldoc/

If you value my participation on this site, please do not remove these links!